# asp.net (asmx) webservices not working in windows phone 7

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-7

I am developing a wp7 app that consumes a simple web service written in asp.net

The web service is working fine in desktop application (written in c#) (also tested in web browser and is working fine) but it is not working in wp7.

Following is the code I am using in wp7 to call the webservice

```
BookService.BooklocationSoapClient client = new BookService.BooklocationSoapClient();
client.BookListCompleted += new EventHandler<BookService.BookListCompletedEventArgs>(client_BookListCompleted);
client.BookListAsync(dId);

void client_BookListCompleted(object sender, BookService.BookListCompletedEventArgs e)
{
       Debug.WriteLine(e.Result);
}
```

and following is the exception I am getting

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.Windows.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.Windows.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll
```

Also, I am getting the following message

```
Server was unable to process request. ---> Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length
```

Comment: In the above code, where are you passing the URI of the web service? Are you passing it correctly?

Comment: @nkchandra yes the uri is correct. I am adding it via `Add service reference`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you try to call local web service on your developer machine, which not allowed by
windows phone emulator.
Try call any public web service available in internet, as example weather forecast